# Kubernetes 1.3.5 setup stop in the middle

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I'm trying to setup a single-node-cluster of Kubernetes on Ubuntu Server 14.04.
The problem is the `kube-up` script stop in the middle and does not actually deploy the cluster as you can see in the output bellow.
I'm following [Goole deployment guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/).

I've download release 1.3.5. In `cluster/ubuntu/config-default.sh I've set:

```
export nodes="root@127.0.0.1"
export roles="ai"
export NUM_NODES=1
```

This is the output of running `kube-up.sh`

```
# KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh
... Starting cluster using provider: ubuntu
... calling verify-prereqs
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (/root/.ssh/id_rsa)
... calling kube-up
~/kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu ~/kubernetes/cluster
Prepare flannel 0.5.5 release ...
Prepare etcd 2.3.1 release ...
Prepare kubernetes 1.3.5 release ...
Done! All your binaries locate in kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/binaries directory
~/kubernetes/cluster

Deploying master and node on machine 127.0.0.1
saltbase/salt/generate-cert/make-ca-cert.sh: No such file or directory
easy-rsa.tar.gz                                                                                                                            100%   42KB  42.4KB/s   00:00
config-default.sh                                                                                                                          100% 5296     5.2KB/s   00:00
util.sh                                                                                                                                    100%   29KB  28.6KB/s   00:00
kubelet.conf                                                                                                                               100%  644     0.6KB/s   00:00
kube-proxy.conf                                                                                                                            100%  684     0.7KB/s   00:00
kubelet                                                                                                                                    100% 2158     2.1KB/s   00:00
kube-proxy                                                                                                                                 100% 2233     2.2KB/s   00:00
etcd.conf                                                                                                                                  100%  709     0.7KB/s   00:00
kube-scheduler.conf                                                                                                                        100%  674     0.7KB/s   00:00
kube-controller-manager.conf                                                                                                               100%  744     0.7KB/s   00:00
kube-apiserver.conf                                                                                                                        100%  674     0.7KB/s   00:00
kube-controller-manager                                                                                                                    100% 2672     2.6KB/s   00:00
kube-apiserver                                                                                                                             100% 2358     2.3KB/s   00:00
etcd                                                                                                                                       100% 2073     2.0KB/s   00:00
kube-scheduler                                                                                                                             100% 2360     2.3KB/s   00:00
reconfDocker.sh                                                                                                                            100% 2074     2.0KB/s   00:00
kube-controller-manager                                                                                                                    100%   95MB  94.9MB/s   00:01
flanneld                                                                                                                                   100%   16MB  15.8MB/s   00:00
kube-apiserver                                                                                                                             100%  105MB 104.6MB/s   00:01
etcdctl                                                                                                                                    100%   14MB  13.7MB/s   00:00
etcd                                                                                                                                       100%   16MB  15.9MB/s   00:01
kube-scheduler                                                                                                                             100%   56MB  56.2MB/s   00:00
flanneld                                                                                                                                   100%   16MB  15.8MB/s   00:00
kubelet                                                                                                                                    100%  103MB 102.6MB/s   00:01
kube-proxy                                                                                                                                 100%   48MB  48.3MB/s   00:01
```

UPDATE 1: I've git close the kubernetes repostiroy to make sure I'm using the latest version. I've also `sudo service etcd stop` and this the the output I'm getting now:

```
# KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh
... Starting cluster using provider: ubuntu
... calling verify-prereqs
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (/root/.ssh/id_rsa)
... calling kube-up
~/take2/kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu ~/take2/kubernetes/cluster
Prepare flannel 0.5.5 release ...
Prepare etcd 2.3.1 release ...
Prepare kubernetes 1.3.5 release ...
Done! All your binaries locate in kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/binaries directory
~/take2/kubernetes/cluster

Deploying master and node on machine 127.0.0.1
make-ca-cert.sh                                                                                                                            100% 4136     4.0KB/s   00:00
easy-rsa.tar.gz                                                                                                                            100%   42KB  42.4KB/s   00:00
config-default.sh                                                                                                                          100% 5526     5.4KB/s   00:00
util.sh                                                                                                                                    100%   29KB  28.9KB/s   00:00
kubelet.conf                                                                                                                               100%  645     0.6KB/s   00:00
kube-proxy.conf                                                                                                                            100%  688     0.7KB/s   00:00
kubelet                                                                                                                                    100% 2158     2.1KB/s   00:00
kube-proxy                                                                                                                                 100% 2233     2.2KB/s   00:00
etcd.conf                                                                                                                                  100%  707     0.7KB/s   00:00
kube-scheduler.conf                                                                                                                        100%  682     0.7KB/s   00:00
kube-controller-manager.conf                                                                                                               100%  761     0.7KB/s   00:00
kube-apiserver.conf                                                                                                                        100%  682     0.7KB/s   00:00
kube-controller-manager                                                                                                                    100% 2672     2.6KB/s   00:00
kube-apiserver                                                                                                                             100% 2358     2.3KB/s   00:00
etcd                                                                                                                                       100% 2073     2.0KB/s   00:00
kube-scheduler                                                                                                                             100% 2360     2.3KB/s   00:00
reconfDocker.sh                                                                                                                            100% 2082     2.0KB/s   00:00
kube-controller-manager                                                                                                                    100%   95MB  94.9MB/s   00:01
flanneld                                                                                                                                   100%   16MB  15.8MB/s   00:00
kube-apiserver                                                                                                                             100%  105MB 104.6MB/s   00:01
etcdctl                                                                                                                                    100%   14MB  13.7MB/s   00:00
etcd                                                                                                                                       100%   16MB  15.9MB/s   00:00
kube-scheduler                                                                                                                             100%   56MB  56.2MB/s   00:01
flanneld                                                                                                                                   100%   16MB  15.8MB/s   00:00
kubelet                                                                                                                                    100%  103MB 102.6MB/s   00:01
kube-proxy                                                                                                                                 100%   48MB  48.3MB/s   00:00
flanneld.conf                                                                                                                              100%  579     0.6KB/s   00:00
flanneld                                                                                                                                   100% 2121     2.1KB/s   00:00
flanneld.conf                                                                                                                              100%  570     0.6KB/s   00:00
flanneld                                                                                                                                   100% 2131     2.1KB/s   00:00
etcd start/pre-start, process 2665
Error:  cannot sync with the cluster using endpoints http://127.0.0.1:4001, http://127.0.0.1:2379
Error:  cannot sync with the cluster using endpoints http://127.0.0.1:4001, http://127.0.0.1:2379
Error:  cannot sync with the cluster using endpoints http://127.0.0.1:4001, http://127.0.0.1:2379
Error:  cannot sync with the cluster using endpoints http://127.0.0.1:4001, http://127.0.0.1:2379
Error:  cannot sync with the cluster using endpoints http://127.0.0.1:4001, http://127.0.0.1:2379
Error:  cannot sync with the cluster using endpoints http://127.0.0.1:4001, http://127.0.0.1:2379
Error:  cannot sync with the cluster using endpoints http://127.0.0.1:4001, http://127.0.0.1:2379
```

UPDATE 2 - It seem that etcd is fail to start because it fail to bind to 127.0.0.1:4001 because the address is already in use.
This is the tail of `/var/log/upstart/etcd.log`

```
2016/08/18 22:28:57 etcd: no data-dir provided, using default data-dir ./infra.etcd
2016/08/18 22:28:57 etcd: listening for peers on http://localhost:2380
2016/08/18 22:28:57 etcd: listening for peers on http://localhost:7001
2016/08/18 22:28:57 etcd: listening for client requests on http://127.0.0.1:4001
2016/08/18 22:28:57 etcd: stopping listening for client requests on http://127.0.0.1:4001
2016/08/18 22:28:57 etcd: stopping listening for peers on http://localhost:7001
2016/08/18 22:28:57 etcd: stopping listening for peers on http://localhost:2380
2016/08/18 22:28:57 etcd: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: bind: address already in use
```

Comment: This github issues seem to be related https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19221

Answer (score 0):

unzip kubernetes-salt.tar from /kubernetes/server to a temp folder, and copy saltbase folder to kubernetes/cluster

Comment: What is that doing exactly?

Comment: can you find kubernetes-salt.tar file from kubernetes folder?

Comment: I'll be able to check in few hours, I'll report back :)

Comment: There is already a slatbase directory in kubernetes/cluster and I didn't find kubernetes-slat.tar file